# Vertically fitting div text between in two other divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something similar to chatting interface, the responded text will be fitted in the center right between two div containers.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Artifical Intelligence</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="main" id="maindiv">
<div class="logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="superbox">
    <div class="middle_box">
        <div id="response_text">Sample Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="chat_tools">
<form id="chat_input">
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="msginput" id="inpmsg" type="text" placeholder="Test">
<input type="submit" style="display: none;"></input>
</form>
</div>
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background-color: white;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    p {
        font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    }
    *:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
    .main {
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
    background-color: black;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
        border-bottom: 1.8px solid blue;
    }
    .logo {
        width:110px;
        height:68.728px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .chat_tools {
        position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0px;
        border: 0px;
    }
    .micbox {
        height: 100%;
        width: 60px;
        display: none;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .msginput {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        color: #CD187F;;
        border: 0px;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        border-top: 1.8px solid blue;
    }
    .superbox {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .middle_box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 98;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        display: flex;
    min-height: 260px;
        align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    #response_text {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    text-align: center;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .main_flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
     }
</style>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/so9k63du/2).

Code works perfectly fine if the length of inner text between containers is significantly small it works fine, but in the cases where text is large it overlaps outer elements:

[image]
([text reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange))

How it should look like:

[image]

As you see if the text is too large it should overflow at bottom only.

How can i properly wrap the text between these two elements? So if the text does not fit in between two elements, It will be scrollable. As you see the current maximum height of text and its container is 100%, but as i understand it should be `100% - div_size` where `div_size` is addition of two other divs in pixels and therefore it must also be wrapped between them (possibly by centering the container vertically).

Now maybe this can be easily done in Javascript, but is there any neat and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: So you want a scroll for you text basically? It would be great with a visual of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Dejan.S By this code, the text can be scrolled down, but the above part which was overlapped can not. Also what i'm trying to do, is to show full text from the beginning.

Comment: Can you give a visual for what you are trying to do. There is not much to go on here. You got some errors in your html structure, placement of css and some not to obvious css rules of what you want to achive.

Comment: @Dejan.S Apologies for late response, I updated my question with visual representation.

Comment: is the logo gone be fixed and always present there? So it will go over the text is the page scrolls?

Comment: @Dejan.S Yes, both of the divs have their position fixed. Also if the text between these two divs is small, it's centered both vertically and horizontally (by utilizing justify-content and align-items flex properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup contains errors. Like the basic html document structure. You didn't have a `<body>`, didn't close `<html>`. You also should place the `<styles>` in the head instead of at the bottom of the page, it's usually scripts that go at the bottom of the page, like your javascript references at the top move those down. Also `<input>` is self-closing so remove the `</input>`. I done some of these things in the example (removed the basic structure things as they are not need in fiddle.

**Solving the issue:** In your case there are some ways to tackle this issue. Setting a height to the two containers you have fixed, then doing margin top and bottom with those heights (as in my example). I'm sure there is a reason for keeping those fixed, but the best (IMO) and most flexible solution would be to not have them fixed and use flex on a container around your divs. That way you don't have to keep track of margins and have fixed heights.

**Solution:**
the `header` and `footer` will take up as much space they need, `main` will take the remaining. This way you don't need `position: fixed;` and `z-index` noise. I provided a shell, you can put your logo, text and footer content as you like in it. For the content to center in `main` you can use `space-between`, add `:before` and `:after` to the `main_text` and that will center your text always.

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main_text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.main_text:before,
.main_text:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: .3rem;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>

  <div class="main">
<div class="main_text">
  start Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium est autem alias suscipit quas magnam debitis itaque repudiandae error minus totam necessitatibus distinctio quaerat, praesentium culpa, eaque adipisci consequuntur a voluptatibus.
  Neque, consequatur dicta voluptates. Debitis voluptates eius recusandae magni accusantium harum praesentium suscipit eaque possimus. Tempora deleniti iure saepe voluptas obcaecati velit sit fugiat et amet ex, quam. Esse maiores iusto blanditiis!
  Vitae doloribus odio atque adipisci autem vel id quis illo pariatur ex labore dolor quisquam nemo accusamus numquam voluptatibus expedita nam laboriosam, quod reprehenderit! Vel explicabo iure eius quisquam, sequi vero adipisci maiores dicta eligendi
  libero necessitatibus laborum aspernatur ab corporis aperiam ipsam dignissimos ex ad rem dolore sit assumenda voluptates fugiat totam. In error eum inventore enim, impedit minima repudiandae fuga accusamus quasi consequuntur cumque consequatur molestiae
  eius labore nesciunt ex magnam possimus recusandae aut explicabo quo aliquam autem nobis? Vel assumenda, placeat repellendus, possimus ipsa maxime molestias dignissimos dicta voluptatem ex quae quia quasi enim error ipsam doloremque reprehenderit
  veniam corporis libero obcaecati repudiandae culpa odio animi, ea qui. Est fuga perspiciatis quis nostrum laborum ullam vel odit dicta accusantium temporibus, minus fugit pariatur inventore debitis quod vitae beatae sed reiciendis nemo velit sequi
  cum! Ullam autem laudantium, consectetur repellat vel sed facilis illum. end
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

and if you want the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weLmo518/5/)

Comment: The `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash either and never has.

Comment: @Rob it does not need one, if it is there it does not "disturb" or break the code. My example is to make it more clear for the OP.

Comment: You're right./ It doesn't./ So let's all put slashes after the periods in our text writings, too./ Get my point?/ Why does anyone do something that is unspecified, not required, does nothing and is ignored?/ (This is a pet peeve of mine/)

Comment: @rob you can go of all you want with your rant about things, I really don't care. "My example is to make it more clear for the OP", if you look at the original html of the jsfiddle, MY belive is that if I could I should make it more clear so maybe op will understand. He/she will get all of that other stuff later...

Comment: It's not a rant any more than your posting about his closing input tag is a rant. It's a technical observation and correction I am adding to your answer.

Comment: Thank you! Everything works perfectly except of two things, Is it possible to center the text specifically between two elements and not for the complete body? Since if the text is small, it doesn't look completely vertically centered. Also for some reason the text is scrollable when it doesn't have to, I tried using `overflow-y: auto;` on all relevant elements but there was no effect.

Comment: Also please note that i'm aware of these syntax mistakes and/or extra closing tags, but considering that i needed to transform the actual code to this specific one, i didn't pay much attention.

Comment: @ShellRox updated my answer. I made you a shell that is way cleaner then a fixed element solution.

Comment: @Dejan.S Thank you so much for helping me, but if i may ask, new solution doesn't have text vertically centered, to do this, i've tried using flex's align-items property which arises the same problem i have in the question, How can i vertically center the text? thanks again.

Comment: @ShellRox fixed

Comment: @Dejan.S That is exactly what i tried, and as you see full text is not scrollable when browser is shrinked. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @ShellRox works for me. Create a fiddle with your code.

Comment: @Dejan.S https://i.imgur.com/iBijWEv.png this is how https://jsfiddle.net/weLmo518/3/ looks in small resolution.

Comment: @ShellRox Sorry for my late reply. You can use `space-between`. If you look at my answer I wrapped the text with a `main_text`, and that got pseudo elements on it, both `:before` and `:after`. Hope this helps :)